# What hooks are fired when components child gets removed or added?

Tags: reactjs

Are there any hooks fired off when one of the components children is removed (not rendered due to conditional) and then added back again? The change happens due to state update somewhere above the component tree, but I would like to intercept it somehow on half way up.

For some reason I had an impression that `componentDidUpdate` should fire in such case, but now I see that it only goes off when update happens to the components state or the state of one of its children...?

Comment: If it is not rendered then no. no hooks are fired.

Comment: Are they fired only if  *existing* dom element is altered?

Comment: I think I have a serious misconception here about the fundamental thing in React... if some child of the component is removed/added doesn't that count as the update to that component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each component has several “lifecycle methods” that you can override to run code at particular times in the process.

The three lifecycle methods are `mounting`, `updating` and `unmounting`.

**Updating**

> An update can be caused by changes to props or state. These methods are called when a component is being re-rendered

So when a child component is not rendered it doesn't fall in any of these categories, ie mounting, unmounting or updating. Lifecycle method exists for components and any change that happens in the child components does not affect the parent component lifecycle methods in any way.

For updating to happen for a particular component, as mentioned above a change in `state` or `props` of that particular component has to happen

Read [The Component Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) from react docs.

Comment: Complex object is passed as a prop to the given component and depending on the value of several of its properties, children somewhere down the tree are either rendered or not. Doesn't that count as the change to the prop of that component?

Comment: Only if the `prop` of that particular component change will a life cycle hook be triggered. Let there be `parent`, `child` and `grandchild`, and `child` pass props to `grandchild`. whatever happens with the props that pass to the `grandchild`, unless the `props` passed by `parent` to `child` or the state of the `child` change, updating will not be triggered.